# How to make local running yii2 CRUD application available online?

Tags: yii2-basic-app

I have developed Yii2 CRUD application using models, controllers and views. It is used locally on PC. I wanted the users to use it online.
For eg. I have www.example.com and I wanted to make this yii2 CRUD application available on this site. What are the steps?

Comment: Not very clear what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very specific, therefore you haven't received an answer. I'm assuming you are asking about how to use your local PC as the server for an online site. Otherwise please clarify your question.

You will need to do the following steps:

- Point the domain name to the public IP address behind which your local PC is sitting. You can find that by going here: http://whatismyipaddress.com/
- In your router you need to set up port forwarding (NAT rules) for port 80 (or 443 if using https) to your computer's local IP address.
- Depending on your Apache configuration (or whatever webserver you are using) you need to ensure it serves the right website. This is too broad a subject that I can give you any details here.

Note that you are now opening up your local computer to the Internet and hence you should be aware of the security implications it has.